# Multiple node-ID assignation

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a neophyte of ROS programming: i need to use the same ROS-node for multiple independent agents; in other words i want to automatically replicate a node (during the launching), each one with its own ID.
In addition i'd like to use this ID in each node in such a way that i can define a topic for each agent (node) using a string and an integer (ID) variable.
can someone help me?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63730/multiple-node-id-assignation/) by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set the node name as a parameter when you run it. And you can use a local topic name, which will be relative to the node name.

http://wiki.ros.org/Names

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0